# How to share config folder between main app and library module?

Tags: node.js, winston

This is my plan to setup myNodeApp, which has these folders:
config, src, node_modules/@myCompany/logging

in the library @myCompany/logging, i have code like this,

myWinston.js

```
const { createLogger } = require('winston');
const logger = createLogger({
    level: config.get('logging').level, // this config is the one from myNodeApp
    prettyPrint: true』）；
module.exports = logger;
```

myLogger.js

```
const logger = require(./myWinston');
const warning = (myWarningMsg) => {
    logger.warn(myWarningMsg);
}
module.exports = { warning };
```

Now in the main app code,
myApp.js

```
const { logger } = require('@myCompany/logging');
...
logger.warning('my warning msg here');
...
```

The problem is myWinston.js within the library @myCompany/logging, it needs a logging level from the main app.
What's the best way to pass this info from myNodeApp/config pls ?

---

Another idea see if it can work,
@myCompany/logging this lib has a config folder, can be used for testing within this lib.

When install @myCompany/logging for the myNodeApp, i can exclude config folder by using .npmignore. So logging will use the config folder from myNodeApp.

Comments pls ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible this way:

1. logger from npm modules can export constructor function:

```js
// file in node_modules/@myCompany/logging/index.js
const { createLogger } = require('winston');
module.exports = exports = function(loggerConfig){
    return createLogger({
      level: loggerConfig.level,
      prettyPrint: loggerConfig.prettyPring
    }）；
};
```

2. and it can be used this way in index.js file, so config is provided properly

```js
const config = require('./lib/config'); // all top level app config is loaded from some file in your project
config.logger.appName = 'web'; // you can customize global config here, for example, you have 2 components - web server and background process, and appName can depict it

const logger = require('@myCompany/logging')(config.logger); //here you instantiate logger with global config loaded

logger.info('Web application is preparing to start!');

//lot of code here
```

Comment: so in the folder of @myCompany/logging, i don't need myWinston.js, just index.js and myLogger.js ?

Comment: as far as i remember nodejs, yes